# Entity Framework: List<T> Bound to DataGridView add back in deleted object to view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, entity-framework-5

How to restore a Bound datarow (add the row back to the DataGridView) after it has been removed?

When I click the delete key on the left side of a DataGridView the UserDeletingRow event fires and I can capture the Entity object (AnswerTable) that is being removed from the list.

```
private void visitorHostDataGridView_UserDeletingRow (object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
  {

  if (e.Row.DataBoundItem is VisitorHost)
    {
    DatatoDelete datatoDelete = new DatatoDelete (e.Row, e.Row.DataBoundItem as VisitorHost);
    visitorHostsDataRowToDelete.Add (datatoDelete);
    SetModified (); // turns on save and cancel buttons
    }
}
```

Later I do a delete when save happens

```
public override void OnSave ()
{

    if (visitorHostsDataRowToDelete.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DatatoDelete item in visitorHostsDataRowToDelete)
        {
            _context.AnswerTables.DeleteObject (item.VisitorHostRecord as VisitorHost);
        }
    }

    visitorhostBindingSource.EndEdit ();

    _context.SaveChanges ();
    ClearModified (); // turns off save and cancel
    MessageBox.Show ("Saved");
}
```

Again, My question is how to I restore a removed row (cancel my delete) and add the objects back into the DataGridView - after I had clicked delete. (I don't need a conformation, I'm talking about I've done some work and realized I made a mistake and want to start over)  I don't want to go back to the database and I shouldn't need to I have all the data, just not sure how to use it.

**UPDATE:**

I had tried List.Add(EntityObject) by itself with no luck (see below). Tried again due to comments.  Updated my code with these three things, in this order:

```
this.visitorhostBindingSource.DataSource = null;
this.visitorhostBindingSource.DataSource = _hosts;
this.visitorHostsDataGridView.Refresh ();
```

Seem to solve the issues I was having, add alone didn't make it show on the screen.  But not sure why I need to do the steps I am doing.  Any additional thought would be useful.

```
public override void OnCancel () // called from on click event of cancel button
 {

 foreach (DatatoDelete dataGridViewRow in visitorHostsDataRowToDelete)
  {
  _hosts.Add (dataGridViewRow.VisitorHostRecord);
  }
 visitorHostsDataRowToDelete.Clear();
 _hosts.Sort ();
 this.visitorhostBindingSource.DataSource = null;
 this.visitorhostBindingSource.DataSource = _hosts;
 this.visitorHostsDataGridView.Refresh ();

 ClearModified (); //disable save and cancel buttons
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in question
I had tried List.Add(EntityObject) by itself with no luck (see below). Tried again due to comments.  Updated my code with these three things, in this order:

```
this.visitorhostBindingSource.DataSource = null;
this.visitorhostBindingSource.DataSource = _hosts;
this.visitorHostsDataGridView.Refresh ();
```

Seem to solve the issues I was having, add alone didn't make it show on the screen.  But not sure why I need to do the steps I am doing.  Any additional thought would be useful.

```
public override void OnCancel () // called from on click event of cancel button
 {

 foreach (DatatoDelete dataGridViewRow in visitorHostsDataRowToDelete)
  {
  _hosts.Add (dataGridViewRow.VisitorHostRecord);
  }
 visitorHostsDataRowToDelete.Clear();
 _hosts.Sort ();
 this.visitorhostBindingSource.DataSource = null;
 this.visitorhostBindingSource.DataSource = _hosts;
 this.visitorHostsDataGridView.Refresh ();

 ClearModified (); //disable save and cancel buttons
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `return` in your event handler method only exits this method and not the whole event handler chain. `DataGridView` does some things before your handler is called and afterwards (where your row is removed from the `BindingSource`).

To state that you really want to cancel the whole event you have to use **`e.Cancel = true;`**.

So to cancel all the stuff done after your handler is called write:

```
if(answerTableDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count>1)
    {
        // multiselect is false so we should never hit this.
        MessageBox.Show ("only one delete at a time allowed,\n Rows removed from view but NOT DELETED from the database.");
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
```

[CancelEventArgs.Cancel Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx)

Comment: Removed confusing code, canceling the delete event was not intended to be the question.  Restoring the data once removed was the intended question.

Comment: If you dont want to reload the whole datasource content you should be able to re-add the deleted data to the bindingsource by using the Add method.

Comment: Add didn't put item back on screen, by itself, updated question with what seems to be working code.